# Use of Excel text parsing functions to extract from a string with complex format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a list of items, with a sample as such:

```
(CompanyName){space}(PartNumber ending with -){space}(Revision Level).pdf
Company 100-50006- Rev. A.pdf
Company Two 6001241- Rev. CN.pdf
CompanyThree 109581- Rev. B.pdf
```

My goal is to get three unique pieces of information using Excel: `Company Name, Part Number, Revision`.

The revision is easy to capture. I am trying to find a way to capture the Company (segregating from the first appearance of any Numeric value). I am also trying to find a way to capture the whole part number.

What function can I use to locate the first numeric character, and do a `LEFT(A2,LEN(FUNCTION HERE)-1)` where the -1 is due to the spacing?

Similarly, I want to do something to find `MID(A2,LEN(FUNCTIONHERE TO FIND BEGINNING NUMERIC), LEN(FUNCTIONHERE TO FIND SPACE OR "REV" AND SEGREGATE AFTER SUCH)`.

Comment: Would you be open to using a custom function in VBA or not??

Comment: If possible, I would prefer to avoid VBA, but sure, as a last resort.

Comment: Come to think of it, I will just change the file names to have the spaces replaced by unique characters like ^ and &, and then just do a Find LEN of that.

Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't know if there might be more spaces in the company name, but for the sample you provided, the below formulae work:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2,9)))),LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2,9)),LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2,8)))

=IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2,9)))),MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,9)+1,FIND(" Rev.",A2)-FIND(" ",A2,9)-1),MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,8)+1,FIND(" Rev.",A2)-FIND(" ",A2,8)-1))
```

It's a bit long though ^^;

It will work for `Company Two`. Since `T` is the 9th index in the string, the default formula will look for the next space, which is inside the revision, and also grab a `-`, which I'm using in the condition. If there is a `-`, it means that there is a single space in the company name, and thus, reset the search for space from the 8th index.

And `MID` just works on the same principle, with `+1` and `-1` to remove the extra spaces.

**Note:** It won't work if there are more than two spaces in the company name, e.g. `Company the first` or names having spaces after the 9th character e.g. `Companies Twenty`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be much easier with the help of even Word's (primitive) regex. Load into Word, Replace All with Use wildcards ticked: first ( [0-9]) with ^t\1 then (- ) with \1^t and load back into Excel. (Copes with the otherwise tricky issue of the number of spaces in a company name).